# Django XMMS2: 'module' object has no attribute 'XMMS'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I just started to use Python so the following might be a really REALLY dumb question but I searched the web for a long time and didn't find anything.

I'm trying to use the XMMS2 client from a Django View. Here is what I have in my views.py:

```
import xmmsclient
import os
import sys

def list(request):
    xmms = xmmsclient.XMMS("tutorial1")
    xmms.connect(os.getenv("XMMS_PATH"))
    result = xmms.playlist_list_entries()
    result.wait()
    ...
```

And here is the error I get:

```
AttributeError at /xmms2/list/
'module' object has no attribute 'XMMS'
```

And the line in question is this:

```
 xmms = xmmsclient.XMMS("tutorial1")
```

The view works fine if I remove all the code and replace it with (for example):

```
return HttpResponse("list")
```

I first thought there was a problem with the xmmsclient library but it works fine when I run this [xmms2-tutorial example](http://git.xmms2.org/xmms2/xmms2-tutorial/plain/python/tut1.py?id=4296054ff1944f951151fe8076ee1734177208d8)

So I guess there is some sort of incompatibility between Django and xmmsclient but I really don't have a clue.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4.1 and XMMS2 0.8

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: I just tried this and it worked:
`def list(request):
    os.system('python /path/to/tut1.py')
    return HttpResponse("index")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a name conflict. My Django app name was "xmmsclient".

So when I did

```
xmmsclient.XMMS("tut1")
```

I was referring to my app module, not the one from the XMMS2 client library.

Thanks a lot to Erik Massop from the xmms2-devel list!